# GROK filter issue

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-grok

`"timestamp":"2023-04-21T06:27:06.255+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/logs"`
(?%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601})\s+%{NUMBER:response_code}\s+%{DATA:error}\s+%{DATA:path}``

I am facing issue to create filter for my response , Please suggest .